# Can't access a variable from another variable in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am having trouble reading between variables in Google Tag Manager.

I am able to fetch data from the data layer, but when I try to access this data from another variable I get "undefined".

Then I tried setting a variable as a constant
[image]

and then reading from this variable
[image]

But I can't even read a constant value
[image]

Any idea why this might be the case?

I tried pulling data from the data layer which worked. The initial value is filled out.

Then I tried to access this value from another variable using {{Variable Name}}, but this value returns "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran a quick test to reproduce what you have, and I see both of them working just fine like expected on every event:

[image]

you have a problem in your testing somewhere.
Like maybe you're looking at a wrong container? Wrong enviornment? Forgot to save code changes?

Oh! There's one more thing! CJS in GTM (and other TMSes) require CSP to allow `unsafe-eval`. Because all CJS is executed with eval. Without unsafe-eval, all CJS variables will always return undefined. That's most likely your issue. Ask your devs about it. You can read more about GTM and CSP [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/csp).

Comment: You're right, it was the CSP that blocked the CJS. Thanks!